# How put Map's Keys in <select> on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dictionary, jstl

I have next problem. In JSP I wrote next

```
<select name='subject'>
    <c:forEach items="${subjects.keySet()}" var="subjectID">                  
        <option>${subjects.get(subjectID).getName()}</option>                    
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

And I get there values from Map. But I don't know how I can get key for choosen subject on servlet

I tried to do this

`String subjectID = request.getParameter("subjectID");`

Thanks

I try to do it
But

```
<select name='subject'>                
                <c:forEach var="subject" items="${subjects}">
                    <option id="${subject.key}" value="${subject.value.getName()}">
                        ${subject.value.getName()}
                    </option> 
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

Error on jsp: Bad value for attribute id

I need show name subject on jsp. But on servlet get ID subject

Comment: Change this: `value="${subject.value.getName()}"` to `value="${subject.value.name}"`.

Also - what is the value and type of your `key`?  Chances are, you want some property on the key, and not the key.  See my answer below.

Comment: @BrandonV Yes, I do some changes in Hardik Mishra answer. But I don't have enough reputation that's why I can't show my desicion(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name='subject'>
    <c:forEach items="${subjects}" var="subject" >                  
        <option value="${subject.key}">
            ${subject.value.getName()}
        </option>                    
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

And on servlet I did next

```
Integer subjectIdByName = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("subject"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<select name='subject'>    
    <c:forEach items="${yourMap}" var="yourEntry">
        <option>${yourEntry.key}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Or, if you want to access properties on the key.

```
<select name='subject'>    
    <c:forEach items="${yourMap}" var="yourEntry">
        <option>${yourEntry.key.theProperty}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

You can access the associated value with `.value` in place of `.key`.

Answer (score 3):

Let say, "subjects" is your `HashMap`

```
<select name='subject'>  
   <c:forEach var="subject" items="${subjects}">
       <option id="${subject.key}" value="${subject.value.getName()}">${subject.value.getName()}</option>   
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

If you want to pass `Key` as value then change to `value="${subject.key}"`.So, On submitting form. You r key will be passed.